# Where does this argument (c) come from? - net.createServer(function(c){...}

Tags: javascript, node.js

http://nodejs.org/api/net.html

I read the documentation for the net module, but cannot understand where the callback argument comes from in this example.

```
var server = net.createServer(function(c) { //'connection' listener
  console.log('server connected');
  c.on('end', function() {
    console.log('server disconnected');
  });
  c.write('hello\r\n');
  c.pipe(c);
});
```

I don't understand what the passed in 'c' is or where it comes from when the client makes a connection to the server. I am a beginner to Javascript so maybe I am missing something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`createServer` is a function that accepts a callback. That is the `function(...) {...}` construct you see there.

The `c` argument is passed to the callback by `createServer`.

If it helps to compare to something better-known, consider this:

```
someElement.addEventListener("click",function(evt) {
    // here, evt is the event object passed to the callback
});
```

Comment: Understood, thanks. But where in the documentation for createServer does it say what 'c' represents? I don't even understand when a function can take a callback or not as an argument in nodejs. Thanks for the help.

Comment: "The connectionListener argument is automatically set as a listener for the 'connection' event." - the function you're passing is the `connectionListener` argument.  From the `Event:connection` doc (http://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_event_connection): "Socket object The connection object" is the only parameter